# How to distort a set of points

Tags: linear-algebra

I have two set of points that I want to make a distortion as illustrated below.

```
A1={{1.85714, 0.742307}, {2.78571, 1.11346}, {1.07143, 1.3609}, {1.21429,
   2.35064}, {2.14286, 2.72179}, {2.92857, 2.1032}, {1.5, 
  4.33013}, {2.28571, 3.71154}, {4.64286, 1.85577}, {3.85714, 
  2.47436}, {4., 3.4641}, {4.92857, 3.83526}, {3.21429, 
  4.08269}, {5.07143, 4.825}}

A2={{1.5, 0.866025}, {2.5, 0.866025}, {1., 1.73205}, {1.5, 
  2.59808}, {2.5, 2.59808}, {3., 1.73205}, {1.5, 4.33013}, {2.5, 
  4.33013}, {3., 3.4641}, {4., 1.73205}, {4.5, 2.59808}, {4., 
  3.4641}, {4.5, 4.33013}, {5.5, 4.33013}}
```

I have already tried to use the Rotate function, but didnt carry me anywhere.

Like for example

```
RotationTransform[-20 Degree, {0, 0}] /@ A1
```

Could you help me?

[image: Distorting process]

EDIT1: First attempt

```
AN = -20;
eta = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[0.001]], PointSize[0.020], Red, 
    Point /@ RotationTransform[-AN Degree, {0, 0}] /@ A1}];
eta2 = Graphics[{EdgeForm[Thickness[0.001]], PointSize[0.013], Black, 
    Point /@ RotationTransform[-AN Degree, {0, 0}] /@ A2}];
Show[eta, eta2, Frame -> True, AspectRatio -> 1.2]
```

[image: ATTEMPT1]

Comment: Have you looked at `ShearingTransform`?

Answer (score 1):

```
pts = RandomReal[1, {1000, 2}];
Graphics[Point[pts]]
```

[image]

```
Graphics[GeometricTransformation[Point[pts],
  ShearingTransform[Pi/4, {1, 0}, {0, 1}]]]
```

[image]

Comment: How about the inversal path, and i'll need the output of the points too.

Comment: Consult the documentation of ShearingTransform.  The inverse is an obvious application of that.

Comment: Something like -17 Degree  maybe works. But how to get the points?

Comment: YOU have the locations of the points!!!

Comment: I'm talking about the transformed points. How to extract them from ShearingTransform?

Comment: Nvm I found a way: ShearingTransform[-17 Degree, {1, 0}, {0, 1}] /@ A1